# Minitest loops return odd number of assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The following Minitest method

```
  def test_not_access
    @bad_users.each do |user|
      @actions.each do |action|
        sign_in user
        get action
        assert_redirected_to root_path
      end
    end    
  end
```

is returning 80 assertions.  Yet `@bad_users` is an array of 10 users, and actions is an array of 4.  The `setup` is split up between two setup block in the `test_helper.rb` and the test file itself.

```
  setup do
    @continent = continents(:one)
    @bad_users = [ ....  *in test_helper.rb*]
    @actions = [continents_url, continent_url(@continent), new_continent_url, edit_continent_url(@continent)]
  end
```

By my math the should generate 40 assertions. So either:
• the action is being evaluated twice for its assertion,
• the setup being split between two files runs everything twice
• or -improbably- another assertion is occuring.

How can I verify which assertions are effectively being run? If the answer is in the second assumption, how can it be rectified?

Comment: Would double check the number of users.  Also easy to print out the user/action combos being run by using puts

Comment: users were double checked.  Oddly some cases the count is proper, others it is doubled up. & had not managed to intercept via puts

Comment: There is something going on in the test fixture as a whole -- very curious that nothing is showing in puts. Any chance you have some name conflict or some inheritance issue?

Comment: Running assertions in a loop in the first place is usually a bad idea - you're really testing the code setup more then the code under test.